# How to update temporary table in stored procedure on the basis of table count

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

My temporary table (`#temp_table_between_range`) looks like this:

[image]

I have tried

```
 UPDATE #temp_table_between_range 
 SET ToDate = DateAdd(YEAR, 100, GetDate()) 
 WHERE ToDate = (SELECT MAX(ToDate) FROM #temp_table_between_range)
```

But it does not fix that last row of last column it just update the max date only

I have to update the last row of last column only

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: What happens when you run your code?  Does it update the table at all?

Comment: yes it update all the column present in todate having max date

Comment: How do you define the `last row of last column`. How do you sort the data?

Answer (score 1):

In order to update the "last" row of a table, you need to know or decide how the records should be ordered.  Unlike some databases, SQL Server doesn't have an underlying "physical row number" that you can reference.

Even if it did, you can't rely on records being added to the table through an `INSERT ... SELECT` or `SELECT ... INTO` statement (with no ORDER BY clause) arriving in the same order every time, even if all variables are the same and nothing seems to have changed between runs.

So in order to do what you want, in a **reliable** way, you need something to sort by.

Let's say for the sake of an example that you want to sort by `ToDate` and then `FromDate`.  Here's an example of how an `UPDATE` statement could work:

```
 ;
 WITH  cte AS
 (
    SELECT   FromDate
       ,     ToDate
       ,     RecordNumber = ROW_NUMBER() 
               OVER (ORDER BY FromDate DESC, ToDate DESC)
    FROM    #temp_table_between_range 
 )
 UPDATE  cte
    SET  ToDate=DateAdd(YEAR, 100, GetDate()) 
 WHERE   cte.RecordNumber = 1
```

I'm assuming here that the combination of `FromDate` and `ToDate` is unique in your temp table, and that those are the only columns in your temp table.  If you have other columns and hence some way to tell two records with the same `FromDate` and `ToDate` apart, you might want to add them to your sort, or to your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: The idea is correct, but you can update cte directly without using joins. `update cte set... where rn = 1`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri  Thank you; I did not know that.  I assumed common table expressions could not be updated. I've modified my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Please create a temp table with Identity column where you will have control on record number as follows

```
Create Table #temp_table_between_range
(
   RecID INT Identity, 
   fromdate datetime,
   todate datetime
)
```

And use update as follows

```
 declare @cnt int
 set @cnt=(select MAX(RecId) from #temp_table_between_range)
 update #temp_table_between_range 
 set ToDate=DateAdd(YEAR, 100, GetDate()) 
 where RecId=@cnt
```

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: To much additional work when this could be achieved with single statement.